# End user sign in and/or registration template example

Tags: users, login

I'd like to create a template that lets visitors either a) register a new account or b) sign in to an existing account.

There's a sample public registration form here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form.

However, I can't find any examples of how to enable a visitor with an existing account to sign into it.

Sorry if I'm missing an obvious link somewhere.

How do you do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do a login form for users with existing accounts: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/login-form

You can see more form examples in the left hand menu of that page.